# Removing quotation marks from beginning and end of a string containing HTML

Tags: html, batch-file

I am trying to replace some place holder tags in an HTML document with HTML formatted text using a windows batch file. The batch works fine except that it includes quotation marks at the beginning of the replaced  text.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    @echo off
   setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
   set INTEXTFILE=test.txt
   set OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt
   set SEARCHTEXT=PLACEHOLDER
   set REPLACETEXT="This is the replaced <a href="http://www.website.com"   target="window">text</a> at its head and tail%"~1,-1%
   set OUTPUTLINE= 

   for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( 'type %INTEXTFILE%') do (
   SET string=%%A
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!

   set variable=!variable:~1,-4!
   )

   >> %OUTTEXTFILE% echo(!modified!
   endlocal
   )

   del %INTEXTFILE%
   rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```

The output looks like this:

"This is the replaced text at its head and tail

Any ideas on how to remove the first quotation mark in the output text without affecting the HTML formatting?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested but this is the basic idea

```
   @echo off
   setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
   set "INTEXTFILE=test.txt"
   set "OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt"
   set "SEARCHTEXT=PLACEHOLDER"
   set "REPLACETEXT=This is the replaced <a href="http://www.website.com"   target="window">text</a> at its head and tail"
   set OUTPUTLINE= 

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=" %%A in ( 'type "%INTEXTFILE%"') do (
        SET "string=%%A"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        SET "modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!"
        >> "%OUTTEXTFILE%" echo(!modified!
        endlocal
    )

    del "%INTEXTFILE%"
    rename "%OUTTEXTFILE%" "%INTEXTFILE%"
```